# Tomcat returns a 404 page using Spring MVC; controller not reached

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a controller and a JSP. That is all. I export my project as a `.war` and put it in the tomcat `webapps` directory running on Linux mint. When I type `localhost:8080/filename` into the address bar, it returns the Tomcat 404 message.

Controller:

```
package web.controllers;

import java.util.Random;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HomeController 
{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayHomePage(Model model) 
    {
        model.addAttribute("display",new Random().nextInt());
        return "/index";
    }
}
```

`index.jsp`:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Random int: ${display}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSP file is in the `WEB-INF` folder under `WebContent` (the default for the Eclipse dynamic webapps project setup). All Spring jars are referenced for project and there are no compile errors. What am I missing here?

Comment: For starters, change your return statement, to return "index"; . Secondly, if that doesnt change anything, you have to post your web.xml and your other XML files. Or JavaConfig if you are using Javaconfig.

Comment: Do you see any errors on startup?  If so, post them.

Comment: Why are you accessing this "filename" page? I do not see that endpoint configured anywhere. Is "filename" your project root?

Comment: @WeareBorg I don't have a web.xml. No tutorial I found said that I needed one, nor could I even find a tutorial on writing one when my friend suggested that might be the issue.

Comment: @GergelyBacso yes, that is the project root

Comment: what is the name of the folder which has been extracted from your .war file on webapps in tomcat that folder name is the URL of your project instead of fileName.

Comment: It was making a folder before, so I know what you're talking about, but it doesn't seem to make one anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured a [view resolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-jsp-resolver)? That would infers a view, like your JSP file, from your return value e.g. "index".

If you are using Spring Boot, just putting a couple of lines in *application.properties* does that. For example, in one of my projects, I put my JSPs inside `WEB-INF/jsp` folder, and have these couple of lines in my *application.properties*:

```
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Then returning `"index"` (no beginning slash) would get `WEB-INF/jsp/index.html`.